# how to differentiate the content of union

Tags: c, unions

I just wonder, if I have a function that accept a struct that contain union inside it, how can I know the content of that union:

```
struct command{
  int *input;
  int *output;
  union{
    char **word;
    struct command *subcommand;
  } u;
 };
```

the function:

```
void readCommand(command cInput){
    if(cInput.u is char) print the content of array of array of char
    else readCommand(cInput.u); //make a recursive call
}
```

any suggestion? thank you

note: I can't change the content of struct command.

Answer (score 1):

With unions, you always need some kind of a discriminator to indicate which particular object inhabits the union. It can be a enum or some other value which tells you the nature of the object.

For example:

```
struct command{
  int *input;
  int *output;
  int type; // <-- e.g. this value is the union discriminator; 1 => word, 2 => subcommand
  union{
    char **word;
    struct command *subcommand;
  } u;
 };
```

Comment: True but OP explicitly said he can't change his structure

Comment: Right. But this just demonstrates the concept. OP would have to use *some* kind of a discriminator. It could be the value of "input" or some other external indicator that is, maybe, not evident in the context he has provided.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. That's the nature of a union. If you need to, you must embed the union in a struct and put a type indicator in the struct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't; you must assume what the underlying data is or have access to other information which can tell you what the current underlying type is.  It is only valid to extract the appropriate underlying type.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive objects of this type from black-box without any information about this object, there is no way to do that without changing `struct command` structure.